# tem algum jeito de mexer na largura do input e continuar auto resizable no Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="col-lg-6" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 900px;">
</div>
```

ps. só coloquei um valor grande no `width` para testar...
Se eu fazer desse jeito meu input não fica *auto resizable*...

só dá pra eu ir mexendo pela numeração col-xs-*? Não tem um jeito de mexer na largura do input e continuar *auto resizable* (fluido)?

Ou seja, só dá pra usar as funcionalidades em *default* do Bootstrap?

Comment: Com `!important` não funciona?

Comment: Você já tentou reescrever o col-lg-6 por exemplo, mas só alterando a % do width? ex: `.col-lg-6 {width: 100% !important;}` Lembrando que o col-lg-6 é apenas uma parte do conjunto de responsividade do bootstrap. Exemplos: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ Explicações: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865158/what-is-the-difference-among-col-lg-col-md-and-col-sm-in-twitter-bootstra

Answer (score 1):

O problema do seu exemplo está na prioridade de aplicação da CSS.

Explicando:

Existem prioridades para aplicação das regras de estilo na CSS, elas são as seguintes, da maior para menor prioridade:

1. Regras com `!important`;
2. Regras dentro do atributo `style` de um elemento `HTML`;
3. Regras com um ou mais seletores por `id`;
4. Regras com um ou mais seletores por `class`, `atributo` ou `pseudo-seletor`;
5. Regras com um ou mais seletores por elemento;
6. Regras com seletor universal.

Essas 6 prioridades são aplicadas quando as regras se encontram num mesmo arquivo. Se duas regras de mesma prioridade entram em conflito, vence a que tem maior número de seletores em prioridade mais alta.

Quando se trata de arquivos diferentes, as prioridades dos arquivos são as seguintes, da maior para menor prioridade:

**Obs**: A partir do item 2, se refere a arquivos diferentes à página HTML em si.

1. Regras dentro do elemento `style` no `head` do HTML;
2. Regras dentro de um arquivo importado por um `@import` dentro do `style`;
3. Regras dentro de um arquivo importado por um elemento `link`;
4. Regras dentro de um arquivo importado por um `@import` dentro de um arquivo importado por um elemento `link`;
5. Regras dentro de um arquivo anexado por um usuário final;

**Obs**: Se as regras estiverem com `!important` elas tem a maior prioridade.

6. Regras da CSS padrão do *browser*.

Fonte = Livro "Pro CSS and HTML Design Patterns" por Michael Bowers.

> Estou mencionando CSS como feminino por causa da tradução de `Creative StyleSheets` que significa **Folhas de Estilo em Cascata**.

## Indo direto ao problema

Como você definiu algo dentro do atributo `style` do elemento, ele sobrescreve o atributo width de qualquer classe do `Bootstrap`, a não ser que o `width` pelo `Bootstrap` tenha o `!important` junto, algo que não acredito ocorrer.

Uma sugestão para solucionar o problema seria alterar a medida do `width` para `%`. Ai ele mantém a capacidade auto-ajustável.